# Фоновый режим

Tags: shell

объясните что такое фоновый режим и как его организовать

Answer (score 1):

Если какая-то команда занимает много времени, то ее запускают в фоновом режиме, чтобы освободить терминал для других команд.

```
команда &
```

Команда выполняется параллельно, в "фоне".